# Apache on Windows throwing 324 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, windows-server-2008, php, http

I have `EasyPHP` installed on Windows Server 2008 Datacenter Edition. Apache appears to be running fine. I can access `/home` (the defaul directory of EasyPHP). However, if I create a directory I get this error on Chrome:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

My `httpd.conf` file has this as one of its directives:

```
Alias /ocomon "${path}/www/ocomon"

<Directory "${path}/www/ocomon/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My `ocomon` folder is under `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www` that is the `DocumentRoot` value.

What could the problem be and how can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was a PHP error that was causing this issue. I don't know why Apache won't show the PHP error in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means that PHP's execution blew up, and that the Apache server had no data to send back to the client.  Check Apache's error logs to confirm.